# Computation of free energy profile as a function of collective variables

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, probability

I was trying to understand the following paragraph in Ref 1 about the computation of the free energy profile of collective variables:

> While free energy can be expressed as the logarithm of a partition function, a free energy surface (FES) is the logarithm of a partially integrated partition function. Given a chosen set of collective variable ${\bf z}=\xi({\bf x})$, this partially integrated partition function is, up to a normalization factor, the marginal probability density $\rho({\bf z})$, and is obtained by integrating the Boltzmann density over all variables except ${\bf z}$ (at constant ${\bf z}$): $$A({\bf z})=-\beta^{-1}\ln \int \delta ({\bf z}-\xi({\bf x}))\nu({\bf x})d{\bf x}=-\beta^{-1}\ln\rho({\bf z})\tag{15}$$ where $\delta$ indicates the multivariate Dirac delta distribution defined by $\delta({\bf z}-\xi({\bf x}))=\prod_{i=1}^{d}\delta (z_i-\xi_i({\bf x}))$ with the single variable Dirac delta distribution defined by $\int f(x) \delta(x-y)dx=f(y)$, for any function $f$. Intuitively, $\delta$ behaves like a function that is zero everywhere but at 0, and whose integral is 1.

I understand the entire paragraph, including why a Dirac delta function is needed. However, I don't fully understand the reason they used ${\bf z}-\xi({\bf x})$ in the delta function in Equation 15. Right before Equation 15, the defined ${\bf z}=\xi({\bf x})$, which means that ${\bf z}-\xi({\bf x})=0$ and Equation 15 would have become $$A({\bf z})=-\beta^{-1}\ln \int \delta (0)\nu({\bf x})d{\bf x}=-\beta^{-1}\ln\rho({\bf z})$$ Since $\delta(0)=+\infty$ for all values of ${\bf x}$ (which is different from the logic of $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \delta(x)dx=1$), it will make the integral divergent, which is clearly different from Equation 15. I'm wondering if I have some misunderstanding here. Originally I thought that they were just using some confusing notations but I've seen equations equivalent to Equation 15 in a lot of different papers.

Ref 1: Hénin, Jérôme, et al. "Enhanced sampling methods for molecular dynamics simulations." arXiv preprint arXiv:2202.04164 (2022).

Comment: where/what is Ref. 1? And what is a "collective" variable?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to provide the reference. Here it is: Ref 1: Hénin, Jérôme, et al. "Enhanced sampling methods for molecular dynamics simulations." arXiv preprint arXiv:2202.04164 (2022).

A collective variable can be any function of the atomic coordinates of the system but an ideal one should capture the slowest dynamics of the process of interest and can be used to distinguish the metastable states of interest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard trick in statistical physics and probability theory. It's essentially a fancy way of changing variables from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\xi(\mathbf{x})$.

To do so, a new variable $\mathbf{z}$ is introduced, but in this context you need to think of the delta function as *enforcing* the relationship $\mathbf{z} = \xi(\mathbf{x})$ inside the integral, because only points $\mathbf{x}$ for which the relation $\mathbf{z} - \xi(\mathbf{x}) = 0$ is true for a specified value of $\mathbf{z}$ will contribute to the integral.

In case you're not familiar with the Dirac Delta function, the quoted passage's description "$\delta$ is infinity when it's arugment is 0 and is 0 otherwise" isn't a great way to think about it. Better to think of the Dirac Delta as only having meaning inside an integral, and what it does it allow only points where its argument vanishes to contribute to the integral. (You will often see delta functions outside integrals,but somewhere down the line that function will get integrated over).